# Achieving desired look for carousel using react-slick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, react-slick

In the image below is desired look for carousel. I am working in React and I installed react-slick library for this. I am kind of struggling to achieve this look.

[image: Desired carousel look]

This is code of my slider component:

```
import React from "react";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "./SlickSlider.css";
import rightArrow from "../../images-icons/png/right.png";
import leftArrow from "../../images-icons/png/Vector.png";

export default function SlickSlider({ images }) {
  const settings = {
    className: "center",
    centerMode: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerPadding: "0",
    slidesToShow: 3,
    speed: 500,
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 700,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          initialSlide: 1,
          centerMode: false,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1300,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true,
          centerMode: false,
        },
      },
    ],
    nextArrow: (
      <div>
        <div className="next-slick-arrow">
          <img src={rightArrow} className="my-arrow" />
        </div>
      </div>
    ),
    prevArrow: (
      <div>
        <div className="prev-slick-arrow ">
          <img src={leftArrow} className="my-arrow" />
        </div>
      </div>
    ),
  };
  return (
    <div className="slider-container">
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {images.map((image) => (
          <div className="image-wrapper" key={image.id}>
            <img src={image.path} alt="property" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And css (I left out unimportant stuff):

```
.slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slick-slide img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: auto;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.image-wrapper {
  width: 90% !important;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  .slick-center.slick-current .image-wrapper::before,
  .image-wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(18, 20, 46, 0);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .slick-slide.slick-center img {
    transform: scale(1.2) !important;
  }


}

.image-wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(18, 20, 46, 0.68);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

So, currently I am showing 3 slides in bigger screens, I gave image-wrapper width of 90% because otherwise images overlap one another on the sides.

[image: Current look of carousel]

Do you have any tips on how to achieve this look for carousel, or maybe it would be better to use another library? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Been a while since I used slick so no help there but Embla is a really good one https://www.embla-carousel.com/ that I switched to a while back.